# What Event If We Click GridViewCommandColumn on ASPxGridView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am using Dev Express to develop a project and using Dev express Gridview Control, in that Gridview ,I used `GridViewCommandColumn` with  `<EditButton>` and  `<DeleteButton>`

but I don't know which event is firing when I click those button, can anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple events are fired in both cases. Click on Delete button will fire [RowDeleting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowDeletingtopic) and [RowDeleted](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowDeletedtopic) events. 
Edit will fire [StartRowEditing](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_StartRowEditingtopic) and [CellEditorInitialize](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CellEditorInitializetopic). Since both buttons initiate callback, many other events will be fired also. This is a [list of ASPxGridView events](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewClassEventsTopic). You should at least read short description of every one of them. 
Also, take a look at [DevEx grid demos](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Default.aspx), especially this [one](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/GridEditing/EditModes.aspx).

If this doesn't help you should describe what are you trying to achieve in more details.